# spring boot with rest endpoints but also JSF

Tags: spring-boot, rest, primefaces

I am having trouble as I have a sample app working with `spring-boot` and primefaces but can't manage to build a rest endpoint. I know there must be a configuration thing to be done between `DispatcherServlet` and `FacesServlet` but I still can't discover it. Can someone provide an example ?. I understand I could set each servlet to start working on a different path but its like being a turkish in the fog...

Comment: please provide any actions you took to resolve the issue along with any guides you followed or tried along the way

Comment: I will... Thanks for your answer ! :) I have been with this unresolved issue quite a bit...  I will prepare something so that you know what I have tried so far...

Comment: Why springboot? JSF is a Java EE technology, so why not use a Java EE stack?

Comment: Because I want to use all the advantages from spring boot... and some other details more...

Comment: @AguLongo, Did you get this to work? If yes, please provide the details.